# python file: Not able to write in 'r+' mode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove a number of letters (depending on the input) from the end of a text from a file and then storing it in the same file:

```
f = open("fileLoc/stuff.txt","r+")
removeNum = int(input("num: "))
prevText = f.read()
print(prevText, end="\n\n")
txt = prevText
if(removeNum+3 <= len(prevText)):
    txt = (prevText[0:removeNum*-1])

f.seek(0)
print(txt, end="\n\n")
f.write(txt)

f.seek(0)
print(f.read(),end="")
f.close()
```

The read and slicing of string works fine, but why is the new text not being written in that file.
This is the output (and the input is 10):

```
C:\Py\youtube>python use.py
num: 10
hello
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

hello
abcdefghijklmnop

hello
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: You DID write the new text to the file.  However, it happened to be identical to the existing text at those file positions, and you didn't do anything to remove the last 10 characters after the text you wrote (`f.truncate()` after the `f.write()` would do that).

Comment: To clarify what @jasonharper said, doing f.write() overwrites existing data but it does not empty the file before writing. To do that, open the file with `open("filename.txt", "w")`, which does empty the file.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right; I was so confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further expand the explanation on the comments:

This is an excellent case where different kind of debugging could help you understand what is actually happening. By the looks of the prints, it feels as if nothing is being written to the file, although that's not the case. So let's run the code step by step after the slicing.

**Text file current state**

```
hello
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

**Variable values when num input is 10**

```
txt --> 'hello\nabcdefghijklmnop'
```

Let's analyze the code:

```
f.seek(0) # You send file object position to the start
print(txt, end="\n\n")
f.write(txt) # Write at the start of the file value in txt
```

Because you are sending the file object position to the start, you are telling the **f.write()** to start dump the string, over writing existing data. So it looks something like this:

- The variable **txt** holds the value **'hello\nabcdefghijklmnop'**. Let's see what the first 22 characters of the file looks like.

**Text file state**

**hello
abcdefghijklmnop**qrstuvwxy

The bold part of the file is going to be substituted by what you have on variable **txt**, which is exactly the same thing. That's why it feels as if nothing is getting dumped into the file.

Another way to have debug this to better understand what's happening, is to quickly substitute for a static value in **txt**:

```
f.write("NEWTEXTBEINGWRITTENDOWN")
```

Then when you execute the program it looks like this:

**Text file state**

```
NEWTEXTBEINGWRITTENDOWNrstuvwxyz
```

It's easier then to realize that stuff is getting written down into the file, you are just not appending to the file, you are overwriting it. Not sure what your goals was (whether to show the different states by appending, or to completely dump the file and start fresh).

1. Appending to the file

If you wanted to append to the file, then an option would be to use **f.seek()** with appropriate parameters, in this case, start 0 and offset 2. (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```
f.seek(0, 2)
f.write(f"\n{txt}")
```

The result on the file would be:

```
hello
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

hello
abcdefghijklmnopq
```

Truncating file before writing to it

```
f.truncate(0)
print(txt, end="\n\n")
f.write(txt)
```

Hopes this was a bit more descriptive.